# I send a request to the server from a lightning component. I don't hear back for several minutes

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps

I have this function in my lightning controller.

```
pdt_rebuildProductInformation: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log('pdt_rebuildProductInformation - entered');
    helper.pdt_cltGetProducts(cmp, event, helper);
    var listOfIds = helper.pdt_harvestIdsFromToBuyProducts(cmp, event, helper);
    helper.pdt_buildListOfToBuyProducts(cmp, event, helper, listOfIds);
}
```

And I get this output from the console.

```
pdt_rebuildProductInformation - entered
pdt_cltGetProducts - entered
pdt_cltGetProducts - about to enqueue action
pdt_cltGetProducts - just enqueued action
pdt_harvestIdsFromToBuyProducts - entered
pdt_buildListOfToBuyProducts - entered
pdt_buildListOfToBuyProducts - about to enqueue action
pdt_buildListOfToBuyProducts - just enqueued action
Date();
"Sat Aug 06 2016 19:29:32 GMT-0500 (CDT)"
```

pdt_cltGetProducts and pdt_buildListOfToBuyProducts record when they are entered, and when they enqueue an action to be acted on by the server-side controller.  But they don't record when the callback is called, because the callback is not called.

After I click around in the application and try to force Salesforce to decide its queue is full, and it had better process some requests, I get this in the console.

```
pdt_cltGetProducts - entered callback
pdt_buildListOfToBuyProducts - callback entered
```

Looking at the log of the server-side controller activity, the controller functions are not entered until 19:31:35, almost two minutes later.

What could make lightning queue up my requests, and not process them?

Comment: Can you share your helper ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava  Someone paid me to write the code.  I've asked whether I can share it.  He hasn't answered yet.  /  I noticed there are two requests in flight at the same time.  Maybe that isn't allowed?  I could put the 2nd request in the .then of the first request, and have the 1st request return a promise.  /  Have you ever had two requests pending at the same time?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava  Hi, Mohith.  The code owner said I could rub off the serial numbers and then post it.  But instead I made a Salesforce support case.  Ritesh and Vikash are still working on it.  I encountered the problem again, in some other code.  So I made a "simple" test case.  It is here:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136644/do-promises-work-in-lightning-ive-made-a-test-program